# Abandoned question: Why does 'npm install' remove my packages?

Tags: npm, npm-install

The command is `npm install --save file-saver` and it returns this:

```
npm WARN The package enzyme is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package gulp-util is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package react-addons-test-utils is included as both a dev and production dependency.

+file-saver@1.3.3
added 1 package and removed 15 packages in 6.536s
```

I know two of the packages removed are `react-google-recaptcha` and `react-async-script`. Also, I'm not using npm's public registry.

Comment: Are the packages that have been removed included in `package.json`?

Comment: @EdmundReed Yes they are.

Comment: What version of npm are you using?